Как выводить в консоль имя моего экземпляра класса
Есть у меня класс Rect с несколькими конструкторами, и мне необходимо отслеживать для какого экземпляра когда и какой конструктор вызывается(+ когда вызывается деструктор). есть ли какой-то способ, который работает как this но выводит имя экземпляра?
{
int m_left, m_right, m_top, m_bottom;
    public:
    
    Rect() 
    { // Конструктор по умолчанию
        m_left = 0;
        m_right = 0;
        m_top = 0;
        m_bottom = 0;
        cout << "Вызван конструктор по умолчанию для " << this << endl;
    }
    
    Rect(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4) { //конструктор с параметрами
        m_left = v1;
        m_right = v2;
        m_top = v3;
        m_bottom = v4;
        cout << "Вызван конструктор с параметрами для " << this << endl;
    }

    Rect(const Rect& copy)
    {
        m_left = copy.m_left;
        m_right = copy.m_right;
        m_top = copy.m_top;
        m_bottom = copy.m_bottom;
        cout << "Вызван конструктор копирования для " << this << endl;
    }

    ~Rect() 
    {
        cout << "Вызван деструктор для " << this << endl;
    }
}




Можно добавить поле с именем и выводить его.
